# Table record saving as string when it should be double

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Could some explain why Laravel 5 is saving my decimal table record as string?

```
$table->decimal('bar', 5, 2)->nullable();
```

**Seeder:**

```
[...] // shorten to show what was created
'bar' => 10.5,
```

**Tinker:**

```
App\Foo::find(1)->bar //= "10.5"
```

I have no issues with `integer` but issues with `double`, `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$casts` to your Model class.

```
protected $casts = [
    'bar'  => 'double'
];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to the Laravel world.